# Add "All" choice to Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django

I have Django ModelForm to filter data by a certain field - 'model_name' with form method="get"

```
class TruckTripForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TruckTrip
        fields = ['model_name']
```

This is my view:

```
def table(request):
    trips = TruckTrip.objects.all()
    form = TruckTripForm()
    if request.GET.get('model_name'):
        models_query = request.GET.get('model_name')
        trips = trips.filter(model_name=models_query)
        form = TruckTripForm(request.GET)
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'trips': trips
    }
    return render(request, 'tripweight/index.html', context)
```

The problem is that I want to add choice 'all' to my form, so i can disable all my filter and get all of my objects.

But right now with this ModelForm I can only filter my queryset

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add all of the fields of `TruckTrip` to inside the form:

```
class TruckTripForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TruckTrip
        fields = "_all_"
```